# How to use mathematical induction with inequality?

Tags: inequality, induction

I am stuck with this question.

Given that $n$ is a positive integer where $n≥2$, prove by the method of mathematical induction that

(a) $$ \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} r^3 < \frac{n^4}{4} $$ 
(b) $$ \sum_{r=1}^{n} r^3 > \frac{n^4}{4} $$

Comment: Can yo share your ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: The proof is equal to equality case, start with $n=2$ and verify the formula, suppose that is true for $n=k$ and prove the validity for $n=k+1$.

Comment: I do not have any idea on how to prove the validity for n=k+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint for the first question:**

1. Assume $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1}r^3<\frac{n^4}{4}$
2. Prove $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}r^3<\frac{(n+1)^4}{4}$

   $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}r^3=$

   $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1}r^3+n^3<$

   $\displaystyle\frac{n^4}{4}+n^3=$

   $\displaystyle\frac{n^4+4n^3}{4}<$

   $\displaystyle\frac{n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1}{4}=$

   $\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^4}{4}$

Note that the assumption is used in order to infer $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1}r^3+n^3<\frac{n^4}{4}+n^3$

---

**Hint for the second question:**

1. Assume $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}r^3>\frac{n^4}{4}$
2. Prove $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n+1}r^3>\frac{(n+1)^4}{4}$

   $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n+1}r^3=$

   $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}r^3+(n+1)^3>$

   $\displaystyle\frac{n^4}{4}+(n+1)^3=$

   $\displaystyle\frac{n^4+4n^3+12n^2+12n+4}{4}>$

   $\displaystyle\frac{n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1}{4}=$

   $\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^4}{4}$

Note that the assumption is used in order to infer $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}r^3+(n+1)^3>\frac{n^4}{4}+(n+1)^3$